# Going up in flames

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

A scream! I rushed up the alley towards the yellow light oozing through the mist, pulling my greatcoat around me. As I neared, a man stumbled into me, clutching at a bloody wound in his stomach.

He clenched my collar in his hand and wheezed, "It's going up... in... flames!"

As he fell to the ground, he pressed a piece of paper into my hand.

[image: Going up in flames]

I grabbed him, lowering him gently, and shouted for help. But he was already dead. What message was he carrying?

> Decode the hidden message

Clue 1:

> Text is just for flavor. Message is in the image. There's three components that need explanation.

Clue 2:

> Draw a pencil mark around the groupings of the squiggles and look at it from different angles.

Clue 3:

> These are the pencil marks I had in mind in clue 2
>  [image: Going up in flames with pencil marks]

It's funny how hard it is to judge how hard a puzzle will be.

Clue 4:

> As has been pointed out, there's an SOS grouping in morse. But the use of morse is, itself, a hint...

Clue 5:

> There's more than one morse message in the image.

Clue 6:

> The whole drawing is one long line. If you were walking the path it makes, you would come to a sequence of points. From that point, you would go back, either to your left or your right...

Clue 7:

> [image: Directionality]
>  Running from the top right to the bottom left. Here's the text:
>  `RLRLRLRLLRLLRLRRLRLRLLRLRRLRRLRLLLLRRLRLRRLRLLRLRRLLRLRRLRLLRRLRLRLRLLRRLRRLRRLLRRLRLLLRLRLRRLRLLRLLRLLLRRLRLLRLLRLLRRLRLRLLRLLRRLRLRL`

Comment: Is it supposed to have many rot13(P)’s, or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: Lol. The message is not JJJJJJJ...!

Comment: Any more hints?

Comment: Does it have something to do with rot13(erzbefr)?

Comment: No. It's more straightforward than that

Comment: It has been 3 years and still unsolved. Guess you can just share us the answer, @DrXorile.

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure it's

> (1) a cut of a picture from [Warming Stripes](https://www.climate-lab-book.ac.uk/2018/warming-stripes/) and
>  (2) the flame patterns hints at the rising temperature as well. 
>  For the third component, I have no idea yet.

Comment: 1 is correct and hints at the theme of the hidden message. 2 is a kind of bonus (I counted it as part of 1 because it's also a theme hint). There's another high level image thing that points towards the detailed message.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is

> SOS
>  As in calling for help, in Morse code.
>  As hint 3 suggest, the image shows 3 dots, then 3 dashes, then 3 dots again, which is Morse code for S O S.
>  As suggested in @gripe's answer, the warming stripes combined with the SOS message probably refers to the global warming.

Comment: You're right so far. But those are 2 elements. But they are clues to the main message

Answer (score 0):

I seem to see

> three figures with hands, feet, tails and heads standing side-by-side.

Not sure if this is correct or what it means.